# Save selected text block on another page in Windows Phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8

I have added following text blocks as part of MainPage.xaml:

```
<ScrollViewer>
                <StackPanel>
                <TextBlock x:Name="Test1" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Height="89" Width="220">
                  <Run>This is test text block1</Run>
                </TextBlock>

                <TextBlock x:Name="Test2" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Height="89" Width="220">
                  <Run>This is test text block2</Run>
                </TextBlock>

                    <TextBlock x:Name="Test3" TextWrapping="NoWrap" TextTrimming="WordEllipsis" Height="89" Width="220">
                  <Run>This is test text block3</Run>
                    </TextBlock>
                </StackPanel>
            </ScrollViewer>
```

I am trying to develop logic so that when I click the text block, the content of the text block can be saved as a link in on another page. The user should be able to click the link saved on the other page and jump to the relevant text block directly. In a way the saved text block will work as a bookmark to the associated text block. I would also like to extend the logic to remove the saved text block.

I am able to add/remove tapped textblock from textblock tbk1 to textblock tbk2 on the same page. This is the code I am using on Tap event:

```
 private void listitemselected(object sender, System.Windows.Input.GestureEventArgs e)
        {


            {
                foreach (var item in tbk1.SelectedItems)
                {

                    tbk2.Items.Add(item);
                }

            }
        }
```

However, how can I add the tapped text block on another page?

Can someone please point me to any reference material or guide me to understand the right approach to achieve this goal?
Thanks,
Aiseduk

Comment: Like Mashhood Adeeb said, you can use local storage but you can use too xml or database for save your data. If you need to play a lot with your data, i think the best is .txt file or xml because it's really fast. You can also implement the messenger management (MVVM light). Good luck

Answer (score 0):

you can use application storage to save your data 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/hh700361.aspx try this link it will solve your problem